# Given a finite group $G$, e.g. $G=S_3$, is there a finite dimensional manifold $M$ such that $\pi_1(M)=G$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

It is known that the standard Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(G,1)$ is uniquely determined by any given group $G$. However, if $G$ contains an element of finite order, then every $K(G,1)$ CW complex must be infinite dimensional.

We are interested in the situation of $G$ is finite and non-abelian, and we do not ask additional condition on its universal covering space (in other words, $\pi_i(M)=0$, for $i>1$).

Answer (score 1):

The following article by Rubinstein constructs such manifolds, asked in the title:

[On $3$-manifolds that have finite fundamental group and contain Klein bottles](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1998686?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

For $4$-manifolds, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15411/finite-generated-group-realized-as-fundamental-group-of-manifolds).

Comment: As far as I could remember, in 4-manifolds case, the manifold can be made to be symplectic?